# Dropdown menu with categories and sub-categories doesn't work properly

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

So, I have dropdown vertical menu with categories and subcategories. It is properly populated but I have problem when I click and select some sub-category. It doesn't happen anything. Just dropdown is closed and doesn't load the new page.
Here is the cat.php

```
function category_list($category_parent_id = 0)
{
// build our category list only once
static $cats;
if (!is_array($cats)) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM cat';
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    $cats = array();
    while ($cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $cats[] = $cat;
    }
}
// populate a list items array
$list_items = array();
foreach($cats as $cat) {
    // if not a match, move on
    if (( int )$cat['parentid'] !== ( int )$category_parent_id) {
        continue;
    }
    // open the list item
    $list_items[] = '<li>';
    // construct the category link
    $list_items[] = '<a href="product.php?id=' . $cat['id'] . '">';
    $list_items[] = $cat['name'];
    $list_items[] = '</a>';
    // recurse into the child list
    $list_items[] = category_list($cat['id']);
    // close the list item
    $list_items[] = '</li>';
}
// convert to a string
$list_items = implode('', $list_items);
// if empty, no list items!
if ('' == trim($list_items)) {
    return '';
}
// ...otherwise, return the list
return '<ul id="nav-cat">' . $list_items . '</ul>';

}
```

This is the script for dropdown

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#nav-cat > li > a').click(function (e) {
            $('#nav-cat li ul').slideUp();
            if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active') {
                $('#nav-cat li a').removeClass('active');
                $(this).next().slideToggle();
                $(this).addClass('active');
            } else {
                $('#nav-cat li a').removeClass('active');
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

When I click on the link `$list_items[] = '<a href="product.php?id=' . $cat['id'] . '">';` nothing happen.
Here is how I pass on `product.php` the `id`. I know is a little messy...

```
  if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
   $id = $_GET['id'];
  $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE cat = '" . $_GET['id']."'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Query failed: " . mysqli_errno($con));
  $line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
  if (!$line) echo '';
      $previd = -1;
      $currid = $line[0];
      if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
      $previous_ids = array();
     do {
    $previous_ids[] = $line[0];
    $currid = $line[0];
    if ($currid == (int)$_GET['id']) break;
    $previd = end($previous_ids);
    $line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
} while ($line);
 }

if ($line) {
...
```

I don't know really where can be the problem. Any ideas? If needed I can post more code.

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: I'm sorry but how can I see it?

Comment: Yes, I tried this but nothing. Like I didn't click anything. F12->Console and is empty

Comment: try refreshing the page with the console open, sometimes the console only records an error on pageload if it's open at the time

Comment: Still empty. I've tried with other websites including stacoverflow and is showing something. But on mine doesn't show

Comment: That suggests your Jquery is fine in any case. PHP errors don't log to the console, Jquery ones do.

Comment: So the problem is somewhere in PHP. Any ideas where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [on the JQuery API for preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/), it says "clicked anchors will not take the browser to a new URL". If you're trying to load content without refreshing/leaving the page, consider using AJAX.

On a side note: your recursive php function creates a lot of `<ul>` with the same id. Consider using class instead.

Comment: I have none `<ul>`'s with same id and they are total of 102. Any good tutorial for AJAX?